# Filling a bootstrap columns background with responsive video

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I have a website grid that I am working on that shows new announcements and blog posts. I have one large column (col-sm-8 that spans 2/3 of the page) that I wish to have an introductory video (explaining/showcasing work) fitting.

I cannot seem to get a video to play nicely as the background for this (trying with YouTube embeds and a couple tutorials around the internet) I have created an image to explain this better below:
[image]

Any help, or just a shove in the right direction would be super appreciated!

Thanks

updated image for better scale:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where is your code?

Comment: Hey mlegg, I have tried a few things, I just generally cannot get a full filling video that covers the entire area of the column. The responsiveness of the video seems to work (even with youtubes embeds, but it never fills) - I'll post an older mockup I have for you here in 1 sec, Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to get a youtube video, or any video to display nicely inside that region, so I suggest you resize the room you have allocated for the video to a better size for the video

Comment: Hey @Oily Barrett - That sounds about right, check out my updated shot.

Comment: Okay, you should probably not be using a youtube embed, to get the best fit you can use the video html tag and style it to fit the area but you do need the video stored locally or somewhere you can directly link to it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a responsive youtube embed code. The width and height were given by youtube. You need to come up with the rest of how you want your page to be.

```css
/* Flexible iFrame */
 
.flexible-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
 
.flexible-container iframe,   
.flexible-container object,  
.flexible-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Responsive iFrame -->
<div class="flexible-container">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/FSvNhxKJJyU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```